# Pass environment variables to .desktop file Exec entry

Tags: environment-variables, .desktop

I want to create a shortcut that executes a program with an environment variable set, for example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Chromium test UTC
Exec=TZ=UTC chromium-browser
```

The syntax above doesn't work (the shortcut is invalid) and I can't find anything about passing env vars in [the spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/).

Is that just not possible and I need to create a launcher script?

Ubuntu 18.